# how to refresh the datagridview when new rows has been added

Tags: c#

hi i am a student of c# and working in winform i have a problem here to refresh the datagridview with new values i have a mainform in which i have a datagridview the data in the datagridview is filled up with the code

i have a second form which is invoked from a button on the main form as `showdialog`and the main form is running behind and there is one more button on the second form which is submit button. there are some controls on the second form from then the data is inserted into the database table, the table which is connected to the datagridview of main form so i want when the form second is opened and data is filled then when submit button is pressed so after `this.hide();` when the main form is visible then the submitted data should be in the datagridview
i have searched and found that changing the datasource would result in the datagridview to refresh with new data so i tried this

```
MAINSOFTWARE ms = new MAINSOFTWARE();
                ms.dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                ms.dataGridView1.DataSource = ms.bindingSource1;
                this.Hide();
```

but it is not refreshing the gridview with new submitted data so now is there any way to refresh?

Comment: no there is no binding issue as the above datagridview is filled when the form loads. means that code is in the load event so when i closed the form then after loading next time the data gets updated in the datagridview. here in this case i have to close the main form and start it. which i dont want

Comment: You can either re-run your database query, or you can invoke the SqlDependency class to auto-refresh the grid when the underlying database table changes.

Comment: glace can you exagerate what you are telling. i am newbie. started the c# few months ago. sorry i didnt understood

Comment: What I mean is, when you need to sync the data from your table to your grid, you can just re-run your database query that selects the data. You can accomplish the same thing using the SqlDependency class, but it's not recommended for large scale deployments: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of the MainForm when you are supposed to deal with the original instance

You could create a `Datatable` property in the Second Form and when its closed bind the `Datatable` to the `DataGridView` in the MainForm.

this code should be in your MainForm in the button click event handler :

```
SecondForm.ShowDialog();

//After closing the SecondForm

this.DataGridView1.DataSource = SecondForm.MyDatatable();
```

Declare DataTable property in SecondForm :

```
private DataTable _MyDatatable = new DataTable ();

    public DataTable  MyDatatable
    {
        get {
            return _MyDatatable ; 
        }
        set { 
            _MyDatatable = value; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: so what can i do here? can you tell me some technique to refresh the data without exiting the mainform and loading it next time.. i want to load the datagridview with new value after the second form is hide. so what can i do?

Comment: datatable property in the second form? how? can you tell me?
and your answer restart the main form right sir?

Comment: look at my edited answer. Just Declare that `DataTable` property in the SecondForm. Do your data manipulation and update your `DataTable`. after closing the SecondForm assign the `DataTable` to the `DataGridView` DataSource as shown above.

Comment: sir your answer is correct. but is you answer create a new instance of main form? means when first form is loaded then after button clicked new second form loaded then after closing the second form, you are creating a new instance of main form? right sir?

Comment: You don't need to restart your main form. if you are instantiating the SecondForm from within the MainForm then the MainForm should still be open.

Comment: I updated my answer, my code will only work if you call `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()` . `SecondForm.ShowDialog()` will pause the code execution in the MainForm until the SecondForm is closed.

Comment: sir where i have to write this?
DataGridView1.DataSource = SecondForm.MyDatatable(); where in the main form?

Comment: sir where in the form load event?

Comment: in your button click event